# How to compute $\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} \binom{n}{2k}p^{n-2k}(1-p)^{2k}$?

Tags: real-analysis, summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-distribution

I would like to compute (have a closed form expression) the following sum:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} \binom{n}{2k}p^{n-2k}(1-p)^{2k},$$
$p\in (0,1)$. I know that $$1=(1-p+p)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}p^{n-k}(1-p)^{k}$$ but I am not sure if it helps.

Comment: You sum equals
$$ \sum_{m=0}^{n}\binom{n}{m}p^{n-m}(1-p)^{m}\frac{1^m+(-1)^m}{2} $$
hence it can be computed through the usual binomial theorem.

Comment: I find $\frac{1+(2p-1)^n}{2}$, is it correct?

Comment: Yep!$\phantom{aaaaa}$